# How to set the next n elements of a Numpy / PyTorch array to some value?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

If I have a variable `side_inputs`, with `.shape` of `[48, 161]`. I want to set the last `n` values to some other value.

My other variable, `side_input` has a `.shape` of `[45, 161]`.

I want to set the last 45 elements of `side_inputs` to `side_input` with:

```
side_inputs[:45,:] = side_input
```

But I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (48) must match the existing size (45) at non-singleton dimension 0.  Target sizes: [48, 161].  Tensor sizes: [45, 161]
```

Comment: _I want to set the last 45 elements_ Isn't `[:45]` the opposite of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
side_inputs[:-45, :] = side_input
```